# How can I keep the gutter width constant when using YouCompleteMe?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, signs

[YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) puts symbols in the "gutter" (left of the editor) for errors:

[image: gutter present]

The problem is that the gutter shifts the whole editor over, and it is only present when there is at least one error. Compare:

[image]

Short of always writing code with at least one error, how can I keep the width constant?

Comment: Or you could simply disable signs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319284/vim-sign-column-toggle for toggling this option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Vim 8 (released a few hours ago), and set `signcolumn`:

```
set signcolumn=yes
```

This is a actually available in Vim 7.4.2201 and later, but you really should go for the major release instead.

Comment: Wow... good thing I didn't ask this question a few hours earlier...

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for this for a few days. Do you know other uses aside from linting for this option?